# How can I bind a select options list to an ng-repeat with a filter?

Tags: angularjs

I have a drop down select tag that looks like this:

```
         <select class="pull-right" id="editActionChargeSelect"
                ng-model="data.editAction.actionType1.actionChargeId"
                ng-change="addAnEditSelectionToModelCollection(data.editAction.actionType1.actionCharges, 'editActionChargeSelect')">
            <option value="{{actionCharge.id}}")
                ng-repeat="actionCharge in data.actionCharges | selectFilter:data.editAction.actionType1.actionCharges">
                {{actionCharge.displayValue}}
            </option>
        </select>
```

The ng-repeat passes an array, data.actionCharges stored to my selectFilter filter which looks like this:

```
angular.module("customFilters", [])
.filter("selectFilter", function () {
return function (data, modelCollection)
{
    var results = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var inModelCollection = false;
        for (var j = 0; j < modelCollection.length; j++) {
            if (data[i].id == modelCollection[j].lookUpDetailId)
            {
                inModelCollection = true;
            }
        }
        if (!inModelCollection) {
            results.push(data[i])
        }
        //results.push(data[i]);
    }

    return results;
}
```

Then I have links in the UI where the user can add in and remove items into and from the data.actionCharges list.  The select refelects this and the options appear and disappear to reflect the user's choices.

The only problem is that the filter is not initializing on load up.  So if the list starts out empty everthing is great.  The user will see their choices removed from the drop down and added into a UI table.  And when they delete a row from the table the option is added back into the drop down, all through the filter.

The data.editAction model is loaded up when I click an edit button:

```
    <a href="#" ng-click="getAction(action.id, 'edit')"
                               data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditAction"
                               class="functionalLinks">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
                                EDIT
                            </a>
```

The edit button calls getAction to laod the model like this:

```
$scope.getAction = function (actionId, populateObject) {
            $http.get(actionUrl + '/' + actionId)
               .then(function (response) {
                   // Test front end exception message;
                   // throw "test exception";
                   switch (populateObject) {
                       case "details":
                           $scope.data.actionDetails = response.data;
                           break;
                       case "edit":

                           // populate editAction Object
                           $scope.data.editAction = response.data;

                           // sanitize dates for action type.
                           if (response.data.actionTypeId == 1) {
                               var actionEffectiveDate = undefined; // if you get null back from database, you'll keep this undefined
                               if (response.data.actionType1.actionEffectiveDate !== null) {
                                   // only make an actual date if there is something stored
                                   var actionEffectiveDate = new Date(response.data.actionType1.actionEffectiveDate);
                               }
                               $scope.sanitizedActionEffectiveDate = $filter('date')(actionEffectiveDate, "yyyy-MM-dd")

                               //$scope.disableSelectionsForEdit($scope.data.editAction.actionType1.actionsRecommendedByLer, "editActionRecommendedByLerSelect");
                               //$scope.disableSelectionsForEdit($scope.data.editAction.actionType1.actionCharges, "editActionChargeSelect");
                           }
                           break;
                   }
               })
               .catch(function (error) {
                   $scope.data.actionDetailsError = error;
               });
        }
```

But how do I get the select to reflect the model through the filter when I click the button to pull up the record.

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example? Are you pre-loading data.editAction.actionType1.actionCharges with the selected items in your controller?

Comment: Everybody, I think this is actually working.  I had an add routine earlier that was pushing the wrong id to the model so it was comparing the wrong ids in the filter.  Then I fixed the add routine and it looked like only new data was working but it wasn't intitializing.  But I wiped out all the stale data and started over testing.  It seems to be working now.
This is  really pretty  nifty stuff.  If people are interested I'll post more context for the example.